# Unable to run the test scripts using Chrome Driver though am able to hit the browser with Driver.get("url")

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, testng

My below code is giving expected result to hit chrome browser with the url and maximize the window.But after that it should go my my test scripts where is have login page and it is doing nothing over there

Please suggest

```
 @BeforeClass
 public void beforeClass() {

         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\NCRExecutableWorkSpace\\automation-ncr\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");  
         HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         map.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
         ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
         options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", map);
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
             driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: doing nothing over there? Where is your script after get url?

Comment: @priyankasharma You don't need the `HashMap` or `window().maximize()` just to spin up  the _ChromeDriver_ controlled _Chrome_ and invoke a url. Remove them and update the question with the text based trace logs.